# If p is a real number such that the series $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of non negative real numbers such that the series $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ is convergent. If p is a real number such that the series $\displaystyle\sum\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$ diverges. Then i have to find value of $p$ for this to happen

How do I start?

Thank you.

EDIT [Exact question is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa7Ce.png)

Comment: P has to  be less than 1 as tgen it will diverge as $\sqrt{a^n}$ converges impliying the common ratio is less than $|1|$

Comment: are you saying that whenever $p<1$ then the series diverges? Because I don't think this is true if you take $p=0$ and $a_n=2^{-2n}$.

Comment: @GWilliams Uploaded exact question

Comment: Can you present the exact question? As Archis mentioned, it is necessary that p be less (or possibly equal, for you to check!) than 1 by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But note that your counter example does not work as it does not satisfy the condition stated, ie there does not exist a real number p so that $\sum \sqrt{a_n}/n_p$ diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

a) As for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $(x-y)^2\geq 0$, we get

$$2\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}\leq a_n+\frac{1}{n^{2p}}$$
So, what if $p>1/2$ ?

b) Put $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ for $n\geq 2$. What can you say of the convergence of the series $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p}$ for $\displaystyle p\leq 1/2$ ?